# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate / findById is returning null as model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose

In my node app, using mongoose on the backend and backbone on the frontend:

```
console.log(typeof elementid, elementid); //string 559578bb66e931bc11c02214

try {

    myModel.findByIdAndUpdate(elementid, {marked: true}, {upsert: false, new: true}, function (err, doc) {

        console.log(err); //null
        console.log(doc); //null

    });

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error); //not executed
}
```

The document in the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("559578bb66e931bc11c02214"),
    "marked" : false,
    //..more stuff here...
}
```

The schema for this document:

```
myModelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "marked": Boolean,
    //more stuff here...
});
```

findById() also does not return any documents.

But I can issue a search in mongodb and find the document:

> db.getCollection('mymodels').find({'_id': ObjectId('559578bb66e931bc11c02214')})

I assume it's because the id is not a string but is denoted with ObjectId()?
The ObjectIds are created by mongoose itself when the documents are first created. So I don't understand why I cannot query and find the document by its _id.

**Update:**

I set the upsert to true. Now a new document is created in the database like this:

> {
>       "_id" : "559578bb66e931bc11c02214",
>       "marked" : true }

The id is not cast into an ObjectId. What could be the reason?
It's working in another script of mine that uses the same schema and database setup...

**The solution:**

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
var elementid = new ObjectId(elementid);
var query = {_id: elementid};
app.uiElement.findOneAndUpdate(query, {marked: true}, {upsert: false, new: true}, function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc); //works now
});
```

If you know why I had to explicitly cast the _id into an Object _id in this case, please let me know.
Drove me nuts and I wasted several hours on this.
As I said, in another script that uses the same mongoose configuration, I do not need to cast the _id.

Comment: In your schema do you have `marked: Boolean` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I do. I have updated the original post.

Comment: Is the err object also null in your callback function ?

Comment: sorry if it is a dumb question but are you sure that your javascript program access the same database and collection (maybe some spelling mistake) ?

Comment: The models are configured in one place. The other queries in the script work.

Comment: normally, mongoose should manage the casting for you. Do you use the same mongoose version in the working and non working script ? Another thing to check is that you don't define _id in your schema: it is done by default by mongoose. But I don't think this is your case since you say the schemas are the same in the two programs.